# Am i calculating the big-o correctly?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, nested-loops

Following loops:

```
for(var i = 0; i < A; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < B; j++) {
    for(var k = 0; k < C; k++) {
      //not concerned with instructions here
    }
  }
}
```

As I understand each loop complexity is `2n+2` so based on that I calculate the complexity of above nested loops to be `(2A+2)*((2B+2)*(2C+2))`. Is this correct? if so, how do I get the big-o out of it?

**Edit 1**

I've learned so much about big-o since this question was asked and have found an interesting visualization that I'd like to place here in case others come across this thread. For detailed reference (way better than student textbooks) and original drawing check out [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#/media/File:Comparison_computational_complexity.svg). There are a variety of [time complexities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities) explained there.

Since the original question involves three nested loops each with a different `n`, then the big-o is `O(A * B * C)` as mentioned in the answers. The difficulty arises when we try to determine the big-o for something like this where `A` is an array of objects (aka hash in some languages). The algorithm itself non-sense and is for demonstration only (although I've been asked non-sense in interviews before):

```
var cache = {}
for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
  var obj = A[i]

  if(!obj.someProperty) {
    continue;
  }
  else if(cache[obj.someProperty]) {
    return obj;
  }
  else if(obj.someProperty === 'some value') {
    for(var j = 1; j < A.length; j++) {
      if(A[j].someProperty === obj.someProperty) {
        cache[obj.someProperty] = obj.someProperty
        break
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    for(var j = i; j < A.length; j++) {
      //do something linear here
    }
  }
}
```

The outer loop is `O(A.length)`. For inner loops:

1. `obj.someProperty` does not exist, we have no complexity per theory.
2. `obj.someProperty` is in the cache, we have no complexity per theory.
3. `obj.someProperty` is equal to `some value` either of:

   1. we have `O(A.length - 1)` where there are no duplicates
   2. We have `O(A.length - x)` where `A.length - x` refers to a duplicate's index within `A`.
4. Everything else, we have `O(log A.length)`

At best performance this algorithm gives us `O(3)` when `A[0]` and `A[1]` are considered duplicates and `A[0].someProperty === 'some value'` as we'll have one iteration for outer loop and one iteration of inner loop (3.2 `A.length - x = index 1`, finally 3rd iteration returns cached value breaking out of the outer loop entirely. At worse we'll have `O(A.length log A.length)` as the outer loop and inner loop at 4 are exhausted when no object has `someProperty === 'some value'`.

To "optimize" this algorithm we can simply write as follows:

```
for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {    
  if(A[i].someProperty === 'some value') {
    return obj
  }
  else {
    for(var j = i; j < A.length; j++) {
      //do something linear here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outermost for-loop runs a total of `A` times. For each iteration, the second-level for-loop runs `B` times, each time triggering `C` iterations of the omitted instructions.

Thus, the time complexity is `O(A * B * C)`.

Answer (score 1):

Constants are ignored while calculating the time complexity

```
   O((2A+2)*((2B+2)*(2C+2)))
=> O((2A)(2B)(2C))
=> O(8*ABC)
=> O(ABC)
```